# why $f_2^{-1} \circ f_1(x) = \sqrt [3]x ?$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I have some confusion in this [statement](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2014/lecture%202.pdf)

It is written that

> Let  $M= \mathbb{R}$   and Let $A_1 , A_2 $  be two atlases on $M$ each consisting of a single map $A_1={f_1},A_2={f_2}$   where  $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}  (i=1,2)$  are given by   $f_1(x)=x , f_2(x)=x^3 $.These atlases are not compatible
> because  **$f_2^{-1} \circ f_1(x) = \sqrt [3]x$**  is not smooth at $0$

**My confusion** :why $f_2^{-1} \circ f_1(x) = \sqrt [3]x ?$

**My thinking** :  $f_2^{-1}(x^3)= x $.Suppose  take  $g= f_2^{-1}$ the  $g(x^3)=x $ .Also we know that  $g(x^3) \neq g(x)^3$

$f_2^{-1} \circ f_1(x) = f_2^{-1} (f_1(x))= f_2^{-1}(x)=x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :- $(f_2(x))^{1/3}=f_2(x^{1/3})=x$

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple question about functional composition, but I understand that when one learns more advanced topics you might get a bit fuzzy on some of the basics, so:

since $f_2(x) = x^3, f_2^{-1}(x) = \sqrt [3]x$

And since $f_1(x) = x, f_2^{-1}(f_1(x))$ is simply equal to $f_2^{-1}(x)$ which is the cube root of $x$. If you're not sure if your inverse formula is correct, do the old "swap x and y" and rearange to have "y" on its own again, this sounds silly but its actually a completely valid method, since the inverse of a functiom, provided it exists, when graphed will be the revlection of the original function about the line $y=x$

Comment: If you surround your math with dollar signs, it should look much prettier